# Flow makes me check for an undefined value that is already defined

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Consider this code:

```
/* @flow */
type ActionType = string
type ActionPayload = *
type ActionError = true
type ActionMeta = *

type Action = {|
  type: ActionType,
  payload?: ActionPayload,
  error?: ActionError,
  meta?: ActionMeta
|}

export function action (type: ActionType, payload?: ActionPayload): Action {
  const action: Action = { type }

  if (payload) {
    action.payload = payload
  }

  return action
}

function login (email, password) {
  return action('LOG_IN', { email, password })
}

const loginAction = login('richard@example.com', '12345678')

loginAction.type
loginAction.payload.email
loginAction.payload.password
```

Flow is giving me errors on the last two lines:

```
31: loginAction.payload.email
                        ^ property `email`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
31: loginAction.payload.email
    ^ undefined
32: loginAction.payload.password
                        ^ property `password`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
32: loginAction.payload.password
    ^ undefined
```

I'm clearly passing the `email` and `password` values, I can't figure out how to avoid wrapping those two values on a check for `loginAction.payload`.

The question is: Can I avoid check for `loginAction.payload` and not have any errors? How?

Here's an [interactive version](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCAxugJZwB2AKjvgLxgDO6ATqRQOYa2EnkUAFAIaZ4QgCZgGIbnl5lKAURYs4LKWFYBXXLPzEFFALK50QjTL3z+GgN4AfVGE20AXNco08AGidhsImLiAPzuBvzConASvs64KmqhHhTKqiyxYAC2pkJJ4ZQmZqj2AL6oqLgAHthq6GBQWhR8lGBCzRRgABRYeGHtXrje-oHRIX2GkUEAlOM2tn5ElMyt7bMtDLYucmV+pFBdAVESU2Dzzs5thgB0h0Eat6N+O84splosHZf8qDsNTYZgeAcdhdXCZISkGBDAKMRgINTiE5nMCvdDvT7tToAcgAMgB5ADiAH0AJIAOSxQ02YIhUOGsPhLEkJSmP3KiwoyyB7HyHQY3Io2LYRAAFkImRAqkJMtgYLgrotMpSwFiAIwAJgAzAAWACsADYAOwADixrNQAt5Vx6ukt7RuIwkVxpkItcGBFCtDydMLhCNQQA) where you can edit the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be impossible for Flow to look at *all* of the code to figure out what is and isn't null. If it tried, it would be extremely slow, in fact it would be non-deterministic (see [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). For practical reasons, the line that gets drawn is that Flow will only check up to the types given at function boundaries.

Your `Action` type declares that `payload` can be null or missing. Even though you are providing a non-null payload as an argument to `action()`, Flow would have to look *inside* the body of `action()` to understand that this argument always becomes the `payload` of the returned `Action`. It doesn't do that - it will look at the signature and only draw the conclusion that an `Action` is returned, and an `Action` may have a null `payload`.

A possible solution for this would be to use multiple constructors, depending on what arguments are non-null, rather than make `payload` optional in `action()`:

```
export function actionWithPayload(type: ActionType, payload: ActionPayload): {...Action, payload: ActionPayload} {
  const action: Action = { type, payload }
  return action
}

const loginAction = actionWithPayload('richard@example.com', '12345678')

loginAction.type
loginAction.payload.email
loginAction.payload.password
```

This now works because `actionWithPayload` guarantees in its signature that `payload` will be present.